# Analysing this sentence: "I have received further confirmation that India and France will attend the debate."

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses, complex-sentences

I would like to confirm my breakdown of this sentence:

"I have received further confirmation that India and France will attend the debate."

- It is a complex sentence

Dependent clause = "I have received confirmation"

- I = Subject
- have = Auxillary verb
- received = verb
- further = adverb
- confirmation = noun

Independent clause = "India and France will attend the debate"

- India and France = subject
- attend = verb
- debate = noun

I feel like there is something wrong with my analysis here and some correction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> I have received further confirmation that India and France will attend the debate.

In the analysis below I put the syntactic functions in bold. The categories of the individual words and phrases are in brackets. We need to be careful in our analysis not to mix up syntactic functions such as *subject*, with categories of word such as *noun*.

**Matrix clause:**

- **Subject:**
  *I* [noun]
- **Predicator /verb phrase:**
  *have* [auxiliary verb]
  *received* [verb]
- **Direct Object:**
  *further* [adjective]
  *confirmation* [noun]
  *that India and France will attend the debate* [declarative content clause]

**Subordinate clause**

- **Marker of subordination:**
  *that* [subordinator]
- **Subject:**
  *India and France* [co-ordination of noun phrases]
- **Predicator /verb phrase:**
  *will* [auxiliary verb]
  *attend* [verb]
- **Direct Object:**
  *the debate* [noun phrase]

I don't believe that *dependent* and *independent* clauses add much to any analysis. The clause *"that India and France will attend the debate"* would, however, be considered a dependent clause because it's marked by the word *that* and for this reason cannot stand alone. Amongst people who talk about independent clauses *"I have received further information"* would be considered an independent clause.

Of course, "*I have received further information*" is *NOT* a clause at all in this sentence. The dependent clause in the sentence is embedded *inside* the matrix clause. It is part of it. More specifically it is part of the Direct Object. The word *"information"* is the head of a large noun phrase:

- further confirmation that India and France will attend the debate

This whole noun phrase is the Direct Object of the matrix clause. We cannot say that the phrase *"information"* or *"further information"* is a direct object on its own. All of the noun phrase must be analysed as one constituent, so the string "*I have received further information*" only contains part of the Direct Object in the clause and should not be considered a full clause in its own right in this sentence.

Comment: I hope you don’t mind that I took the liberty of neating up your bullet points a little to make them more logically grouped. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Not at all! I spent ages fiddling with them to try to make them look ok, but gave up. It's much better now. Thanks :)